An skew-symmetric matrix with respect to an orthonormal basis
Let $(V, g)$ be an euclidean vector space and $f$ and endomorphism of $V$ such that
$$
g(f(u), v) = -g(u, f(v)),\ \text{for all}\ u, v \in V.
$$
a) Prove that $\ker f$ and $im f$ are orthogonal subspaces of $V$.
b) Prove that $V = \ker f \oplus im f$.
c) Prove that if $B$ is an orthonormal basis of $(V, g)$ then $M(g, B)$ is skew-symmetric
I´ve solved (a) and (b):
a) Suppose that $u \in \ker f$ and $v \in im f$, so $v = f(w)$ for some $w \in V$. Then
$$
g(u, v) = g(u, f(w)) = -g(f(u), w) = -g(0, w) = 0,
$$
so $ker f$ and $im f$ are orthogonal subspaces.
b) Since $f$ is an endomorphism, we have $V = \ker f + im f$. Suppose that $v \in \ker f$ and $v \in im f$, so that $f(v) = 0$ and $v = f(u)$ for some $u \in V$. Then
$$
g(v, v) = g(f(u), v) = -g(u, f(v)) = -g(u, 0) = 0.
$$
Since $g$ is euclidean, the equality implies that $v = 0$. Hence,
$$
V = \ker f \oplus im f.
$$
For (c) I´ve thought about using part (b), but I´m a bit stuck right now. Any hint?
